# how can I use ts to choose between types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

please tell me. I understand that I should use generics, but I don't understand exactly how. I would like typescript to understand that if I do a check for A, then there are options in the object and vice versa.

```js
type Options = {
  items: Array<string>;
};
type A = {
  options: Options;
  a: string;
};

type B = {
  b: number;
};

type AB = A | B;

function test(p: AB) {
  // if(p.a) Property 'a' does not exist on type 'AB'.
  // if(p.b) Property 'b' does not exist on type 'AB'.
}
```

Comment: just use `if ("a" in p)` instead of `if (p.a)`

Comment: yes, but there is a problem: I can pass an object to the argument in which there will be both a and b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one else came up with something better, here is how I would handle it.

```
function test(p: AB) {
  if ("options" in p && "a" in p){
       p
    // ^? A
  } 
  if ("b" in p) {
        p
    // ^? B
  }
}
```

I would check for both the `options` property and the `a` property to make sure that `p` is of type `A`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzlAvFA3gKCigWAgFs0AuKAQQCdaBDEAHjWFoRQHMA%20AbjwBfAaEg0suAlCTxk6KnESo0AwgypsO3AcLx5R0AEIT8hAEZUUAV1JmItHQP3ho1Y9mpQAPlENOAZlYoAMZKKFAkbAAUYFRuAJSShAj%20UFEARDJhaOlE4WBQAGSFUOkMuZxQYPGmhHVVUoQA9E1QAHoA-FKCUBAANmjQtfWEYI1QLe1dhIJCQA)